# How to connect database with InDesign using script

Tags: javascript, api, scripting, fetch-api, adobe-indesign

I am trying to connect with some database and use InDesign to publish data results. I would like to do it with JavaScript(I have OS Windows). Unfortunately Normal JavaScript fetch request doesn't work. I guess I should use some method from InDesign object model instead.

Example

```
fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => alert(data));
```

Comment: I'm mostly code for the classic CS6. So I can be wrong on this matter. As far as I can tell the modern versions of Adobe apps have the two engines: the classic **Extendscript** to handle with layout, menus and panels, etc; and **CEP** https://www.adobe.io/apis/creativecloud/cep.html which is basically a web browser inside Adobe apps. The latter can do many tricks from the web realm. Extendscript has no web tools like `fetch`, etc. But CEP panels have no direct access to the layout. CEP just runs jsx scripts. So, yes, you can do it. But you need to learn how the CEP works.

Comment: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_9.x/Documentation/CEP%209.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md

Comment: https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/Getting-Started-guides